# Which mathematical operations does secp256k1 point multiplication use?

Tags: elliptic-curves

To convert a bitcoin private key to a public key, the secp256k1 point multiplication math is used.

Could I – theoretically – convert a private key to a public key just using the four arithmetic operations and scalars. If not, what else would be absolutely necessary?

I want to do it using a purely mechanical engine, so the answer to this question will help me clarify my problem.